# Searching with sphinx using thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, thinking-sphinx

I have strange error in my rails app using thinking sphinx. When i enter symbols like `@` or `-` or `$` i have error `syntax error, unexpected TOK_FIELDLIMIT`. I tried to escape those symbols, but that didn't work. Is there any built in thinking_sphinx methods to skip symbols like these?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Thinking Sphinx are you using? Escaping queries are done slightly differently  depending on the version of Thinking Sphinx (or more to the point, the protocol used for communicating with Sphinx).

TS v3 releases use SphinxQL, and you can escape input for those with `Riddle::Query.escape("foo@-$")`. v1/v2 releases use Sphinx's binary protocol, and `Riddle.escape("bar@-$")` covers that appropriately instead.